# How Ultrasonic diffuser work?

Tags: thermodynamics, oscillators, resonance, evaporation

i have studied A2 physics where i have learnt resonance and evaporation, i wondered how the ultrasonic diffuser work. my inital thought was that i guess water have it's own natural frequency, the diffuser is basically a vibrator, so it adjust to natrual frequency of water and made water to resonance, some water reached higher speed and able to get away from surface, then it become fog. But the problem is that  i can not find any detailed information online to make sure i'm thinkning right thing.

Comment: I guess that reading at Wikipedia can be informative https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonication#:~:text=Sonication%20is%20the%20mechanism%20used,such%20as%20spectacles%20and%20jewelry.

Comment: ok i will have a look, thanks